# Motorola G Third Gen SD Card

Tags: sd-card, motorola

I have a Motorola Moto G Third Gen with me (the budget phone) with an 32 GB sd card (Micro SD HC-I) from ADATA. When I upload videos to YouTube or Facebook, my Storage & USB menu tells me that the SD card needs to be pulled out and put back in again for it to work. And it works, but that is beyond unacceptable. How can I bypass this issue?

Thank You very much in advance!

Comment: Is your SD card configured as adopted (internal) or portable (external) storage?

Comment: Internal. I managed to download the information from it by chance, then did a full format and reformatted it again as Internal memory, now it looks like everything is running okay again. But I don't get it, that card is brand new and had nothing but a few photos on it, this is really strange.

Comment: This issue has been seen with cheaper Microsd cards, it's seems they are minutely thinner than "standard" ones and will momentarily lose connection, try putting a single layer of Scotch tape on the back of the SD card or switch to a Samsung or SanDisk card

Comment: It's been three days now, everything is okay with the phone, and the card is certainly not marked as cheap where I live.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying a different class SD card,  like an xc and make sure it's 32gb max as that's what the moto e can handle. And first off make sure you have it set so all files are saved to the SD card and not the device.

Comment: Yes, I have set it as internal storage and the Motorola process itself said so. But... problem still appears.

Comment: You need to set it to EXTERNAL STORAGE so files save to your SD card. That should solve the issue.